# Table layout - text does not stay on the top of div

Tags: html, css

I created simple layout with two table-cells. When i add iframe with map, the text in the red div moves under that map, but i wanna that it stays on the top. What m i doing wrong here?
Thank you.

[https://jsfiddle.net/skp114ab](https://jsfiddle.net/skp114ab/)

HTML:

```
  <div class="container">
  <div class="map">
    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d7098.94326104394!2d78.0430654485247!3d27.172909818538997!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1385710909804" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
      text
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}

.map {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
}
.block {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
}
```

Comment: Add `vertical-align: top` to `.block`. Updated fiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/skp114ab/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `vertical-align: top` to `.block`. Updated [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.ne/skp114ab/1)

Answer (score 1):

Try this Add `vertical-align:top;` for ".block"

```css
.container {
    display: table;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    position:absolute;
}

.map {
    background-color: blue;
    display: table-cell;
}
.block {
    background-color: red;
    width: 300px;
    display: table-cell;
  vertical-align:top;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="map">
  <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m14!1m12!1m3!1d7098.94326104394!2d78.0430654485247!3d27.172909818538997!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1385710909804" width="100%" height="100%" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>
  </div>
  <div class="block">
      text
  </div>
</div>
```